# Regex matches something that shouldn't

Tags: regex, vba

I am having a problem with regex. Does anyone know why regex switches space with nothing if 2nd word contains capital letters and ends with numbers?

```
With regEx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
End With
regEx.Pattern = "\s*([\||\&|!<>|!>=|!<=|!=|!<|!>|<>|>=|<=|=|<|>|IN|!IN|LIKE|!LIKE|ISNULL|ISNOTNULL|ISEMPTY|ISNOTEMPTY|!])\s*"
sstr = regEx.Replace(sstr, "$1")
```

If `sstr = "Matica M20"` output to sstr should be "Matica M20" but I get "MaticaM20"

While if `sstr = "Matica m20"` the output to sstr is "Matica m20"
Why is that?

What causes the match in the first case?

Comment: For that particular string, your pattern is essentially something like this `\s*([M])\s*`. Now, it should be easy enough to figure out what's happening. See it here: https://regex101.com/r/QAwKeZ/1/. The first thing you need to do is remove `[` and `]` from your original pattern. [You're using them wrong](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: I see. So when doing "or" in regex you don't need [ ]. I assume "or" is contained within ( ) ?

Comment: Yes, `[]` is called a character class and `[ab]` matches the same thing that `a|b` would match.

Comment: Thanks. I had perl in my head... so I messed up here.